# Как реализовать веб админ панель для aiogram bot?

Tags: python, aiogram

В данный момент я пишу бота для тренировки заданий ЕГЭ на aiogram v.2. Мне очень хочется сделать админ панель, например как в Django, что бы можно было  добавлять , удалять , редактировать задания, которые я храню в бд. Очень сильно хочется увидеть рабочий пример , ну или хотя бы направление куда копать.

Comment: Т.е. направление джанго, коли вы его приводите, вас не устраивает?

Comment: Интересно, с каких пор на ЕГЭ необходимы знания разработки чат-ботов. А вообще, смотрите в сторону fast api, js и etc, к примеру.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыковm Дело в том, что адекватных темплейтов на просторе я не смог найти, а самостоятельные попытки ни к чему не привели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На просторах интернета я наткнулся на хороший темплейт: https://github.com/SanjarbekSaminjonov/django-aiogram-template